# How to declare DateTime property with proper DateTimeKind?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to have something like this:

```
[Kind=DateTimeKind.Utc]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

Is this possible to set Kind declaratively like that? What is a proper syntax? I have stub classes to use in my JSON WCF Webservice and when other end (Java client) get's dates - they all like:

123456000-0500

Where "-0500" is my timezone and if I take only left part then it's not correct UTC date(I have to substract 5 hours). I'd rather fix it on server.

**EDIT**:

1. I save all dates in database (SQL Server) as UTC. I never deal with local dates except when need to display it.
2. I have simple class which I pass as response in my WCF service - JSON. When I populate this class - I query database with EF and assign values in this class.
3. On client, which is Android phone with Java - I use Gson library to deserialize. Gson can't deserialize WCF format, so I already wrote my ugly deserializer like this:

   public class GsonDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer
   {
       public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
       {
           String s = json.getAsString();
           s = s.replace("/Date(", "");
           s = s.replace(")/", "");

   ```
       //if there us no data passed in - that means NULL
       if (s.equals("")) return null;

       //If we got timezone info with this date - cut it off
       if (s.length() > 5 && (s.indexOf("-") == s.length()-5 || s.indexOf("+") == s.length()-5))
       {
           s = s.substring(0, s.length()-5);
       }

       Long l = Long.valueOf(s);

       return new Date(l);

   }
   ```

   }

I thought that WCF passes "-0500" only for information so client knows which timezone it should be converted to. But no. It passes left number with 5 hours added. So, I don't want server to be "smart" and just want it to pass all dates as "-0000"

Comment: are you wanting to show the adjusted time at the server or at the client?

Comment: I want client to receive 123456000-0000 - I don't want WCF to take my UTC date(which I get from DB) and pass it as local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finishing my own function. Now when I deserialize I take into account time zone portion.

```
public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String s = json.getAsString().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        //if there us no data passed in - that means NULL
        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        //If we got timezone info handle separately:
        long offset = 0;
        if (s.length() > 5 && (s.indexOf("-") == s.length()-5 || s.indexOf("+") == s.length()-5))
        {
            //get offset minutes
            offset = Long.valueOf(s.substring(s.length()-4, s.length()-2))*60 + Long.valueOf(s.substring(s.length()-2, s.length()));
            //Apply direction
            if (s.indexOf("-") == s.length()-5) offset = -offset;

            //Cutoff offset
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-5);
        }

        return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that date is a proper [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so the other end should accept it. If you can't change that, or you don't want to, you can do the following:

```
private DateTime m_createdOn;
public DateTime CreatedOn
{
    get { return m_createdOn; }
    set { m_createdOn = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
}
```

**EDIT:** You mean the date with timezone is wrong? In that case, you should probably let your database layer create the dates with the proper `DateKind`.

Comment: See my EDIT in main post. And how do I tell SQL Server what kind is that? It's just DateTime and I always store UTC dates there.